# DateTime Parse from FTP

Tags: asp.net, datetime, ftp

I am using FTP and I have retrieved a list of Files.   In the files command line there is a datetime field.

It reads
`11-13-13  11:31AM`

Can anyone tell me how I can parse this.  I thought this might work.

`DateTime.ParseExact(date,"MM-DD-YY HH:MMtt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat);` But i still get an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

day should be dd not DD

Year should be yy not YY

since hour is 12 hour format it should be hh also MM (minutes should be mm)

DateTime.ParseExact(date,"MM-dd-yy hh:mmtt",...)

eg:-

DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("11-13-13 11:31AM", "MM-dd-yy hh:mmtt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Response.Write(date);